# My container running ntpd, keeps closing because of exit 0

Tags: bash, docker

In my container I have this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

DAEMON=/usr/sbin/ntpd
PIDFILE=/var/run/ntpd.pid

#test -x ${DAEMON} || exit 5

if [ -r /etc/default/ntp ]; then
        . /etc/default/ntp
fi

if [ /var/lib/ntp/ntp.conf.dhcp -nt /etc/ntp.conf ]; then
        NTPD_OPTS="${NTPD_OPTS} -c /var/lib/ntp/ntp.conf.dhcp"
fi

function start {
    exec bash -c "exec ${DAEMON} -p ${PIDFILE} ${NTPD_OPTS}" > /dev/null 2>&1
}

start
```

I try using `trap` but whatever I do every time my container stops and I think it's because `/usr/sbin/ntpd` sends a `exit 0`.

Is there another way to just stop the exit signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `ntpd` forks a child process to run in the background, and then the main process exits. If you don't want this, use the `-n` option.

```
function start {
    exec bash -c "exec ${DAEMON} -n -p ${PIDFILE} ${NTPD_OPTS}" > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Wasted so much time on this. I just tried it without `> /dev/null 2>&1` works well too.